# What is a simple solution for dynamic mysqli bind_param arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

To build a bind_param dynamically, I have found this on other SO posts.

```
call_user_func_array(array(&$stmt, 'bindparams'), $array_of_params);
```

Can someone break this down in plain english for me? I get especially lost that the first argument is an array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
array($stmt, 'bindparams')
```

is PHP's way of identifying method bind_params on the object `$stmt`, since PHP 5 you don't need to use the `&` in front any longer (and mysqli is PHP 5 so this looks like a glitch in the older post).

you can see a similar example [here](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array)

so

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bindparams'), $array_of_params);
```

basically means

```
$stmt->bind_params($array_of_params[0], $array_of_params[1] ... $array_of_params[N])
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot pass the result of e.g. 
`$userid == "ALL"` 
to a mysqli-statement-Object's bind_param method, because this method wants the parameters to be passed by reference. Obviously this is not possible with the result of an  expression evaluated "in place".

As a workaround, I changed the program's second part  to

```
$userIdEmpty = $userid == "ALL";
$locationEmpty = $location = "ALL";
$stmt->bind_param( "siiiii", 
  "active", $userid, $userIdEmpty,
  $location, $locationEmpty,
  $limit);
```

Like that, the result of the boolean operation can be passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much simper way to do this.

create this prepared statement:

```
select * from mytable 
 where status = ? and (userid = ? or ?) 
 and (location = ? or ?)
 order by `date` desc, time desc
 limt ?
```

and pass the args to bind like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( [statement above] );
$stmt->bind_param( "siiiii", 
  "active", $userid, $userid == "ALL", 
  $location, $location == "ALL", 
  $limit);
```

The predicate `(user_id = ? or ?)` will be true when the user_id equals the first replaced parameter, or when the second replaced parameter is true.

`$user_id` when converted to an int will be its value when it's a string representation of a number, or zero otherwise. The expression `$userid == "ALL"` will evaluate to a boolean, which will be passed to `bind_param`. We can't tell `bind_param` that a parameter is a boolean (the format string only understand string, int, double, and blob), so bind_param will convert the boolean to an int, which works for us.

As long as no user_id or location_id in the database is zero, you're fine.