# Is it conventional to user PHP's eval function within an sql statement

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement, eval

I'm not sure if the way I'm coding is the most conventional. I have created a MySQLi class with prepared statements; however, I use an eval() in the "bind_params" statement to dynamically bind the parameters in my framework. The reason I chose to do so is to use the same application in further developments, so none of the dynamics of the queries would be controlled by a user other than myself or another developer.

My question is should I use another way of implementing dynamic queries in my class or am I safe with a `eval("\$stmt->bind_param(\$types, $array")`.

Note: Please go easy on me, I'm self taught and have much to learn.

Comment: It's not conventional to use eval anywhere.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755036/what-is-a-simple-solution-for-dynamic-mysqli-bind-param-arguments-in-php

Comment: @rjdown Exactly the answer I needed. lmbo I must've read similar questions a million times that post just showed me why my call_user_func_array() wasn't working. Cool beans. Thanks. You should post it as an answer so I can select it

Comment: Think you meant to ping @Matt

Comment: Lol oh yeah. You're right. thanks @Matt. Both you guy's answer was definitely helpful